# Converter XML para array em PHP

Tags: php, array, xml

Estou a ir buscar nomes de artigos por este link:

```
[http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/index:SCIDIR?query=heart+attack&apiKey=20d0c7953f56925f725afe204869dadb&xml-decode=true&httpAccept=application%2Fxml][1]
```

Está-me a devolver o resultado em XML, agora preciso de converter o resultado para dentro de um array. Estou a usar a seguinte função:

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/index:SCIDIR?query=heart+attack&apiKey=20d0c7953f56925f725afe204869dadb&xml-decode=true&httpAccept=application%2Fxml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($page);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

O problema é que nem todos os campos são passados para o array, por exemplo no title do artigo não passa para o array. Existe outra função que passe os campos todos o XML para o array? Também experimentei do seguinte modo mas o resultado é identico:

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1);
$array = array($xml->getName() => $array);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para *converter* corretamente um XML para Array sem a necessidade de usar JSON, pode ser usado o método abaixo para isso.

```
function xmlToArray($xml, $options = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        'namespaceSeparator' => ':', // você pode querer que isso seja algo diferente de um cólon
        'attributePrefix' => '@',    // para distinguir entre os nós e os atributos com o mesmo nome
        'alwaysArray' => array(),    // array de tags que devem sempre ser array
        'autoArray' => true,         // só criar arrays para as tags que aparecem mais de uma vez
        'textContent' => '$',        // chave utilizada para o conteúdo do texto de elementos
        'autoText' => true,          // pular chave "textContent" se o nó não tem atributos ou nós filho
        'keySearch' => false,        // pesquisa opcional e substituir na tag e nomes de atributos
        'keyReplace' => false        // substituir valores por valores acima de busca
    );
    $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);
    $namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
    $namespaces[''] = null; // adiciona namespace base(vazio) 

    // Obtém os atributos de todos os namespaces
    $attributesArray = array();
    foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
        foreach ($xml->attributes($namespace) as $attributeName => $attribute) {
            // Substituir caracteres no nome do atributo
            if ($options['keySearch']) $attributeName =
                    str_replace($options['keySearch'], $options['keyReplace'], $attributeName);
            $attributeKey = $options['attributePrefix']
                    . ($prefix ? $prefix . $options['namespaceSeparator'] : '')
                    . $attributeName;
            $attributesArray[$attributeKey] = (string)$attribute;
        }
    }

    // Obtém nós filhos de todos os namespaces
    $tagsArray = array();
    foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
        foreach ($xml->children($namespace) as $childXml) {
            // Recursividade em nós filho
            $childArray = xmlToArray($childXml, $options);
            list($childTagName, $childProperties) = each($childArray);

            // Substituir caracteres no nome da tag
            if ($options['keySearch']) $childTagName =
                    str_replace($options['keySearch'], $options['keyReplace'], $childTagName);
            // Adiciona um prefixo namespace, se houver
            if ($prefix) $childTagName = $prefix . $options['namespaceSeparator'] . $childTagName;

            if (!isset($tagsArray[$childTagName])) {
                // Só entra com esta chave
                // Testa se as tags deste tipo deve ser sempre matrizes, não importa a contagem de elementos
                $tagsArray[$childTagName] =
                        in_array($childTagName, $options['alwaysArray']) || !$options['autoArray']
                        ? array($childProperties) : $childProperties;
            } elseif (
                is_array($tagsArray[$childTagName]) && array_keys($tagsArray[$childTagName])
                === range(0, count($tagsArray[$childTagName]) - 1)
            ) {
                $tagsArray[$childTagName][] = $childProperties;
            } else {
                $tagsArray[$childTagName] = array($tagsArray[$childTagName], $childProperties);
            }
        }
    }

    // Obtém o texto do nó
    $textContentArray = array();
    $plainText = trim((string)$xml);
    if ($plainText !== '') $textContentArray[$options['textContent']] = $plainText;

    $propertiesArray = !$options['autoText'] || $attributesArray || $tagsArray || ($plainText === '')
            ? array_merge($attributesArray, $tagsArray, $textContentArray) : $plainText;

    // Retorna o nó como array
    return array(
        $xml->getName() => $propertiesArray
    );
}
```

[**Fonte**](http://outlandish.com/blog/xml-to-json/)

Exemplo de utilização:

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/index:SCIDIR?query=heart+attack&apiKey=20d0c7953f56925f725afe204869dadb&xml-decode=true&httpAccept=application%2Fxml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($page);
$arrayData = xmlToArray($xml);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayData);
```

<kbd>[**Codepad.viper-7 Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/k86M49)</kbd>

Comment: Obrigado! só estou com problema com esta solução, funciona tudo ok mas como posso contar as entradas do array? estou a tentar usar count($array['search-results']) mas dá o seguinte erro: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @pc_oc `echo count($arrayData['search-results']);` parece funcionar para mim.

Answer (score 3):

Não aconselharia fazer esta gambiarra com JSON. Na [documentação do SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php#112710) tem uma exemplo de como criar um *array* à partir do XML.

```
function XML2Array($xmlContent, $out = array()){
    $xmlObject = is_object($xmlContent) ? $xmlContent : simplexml_load_string($xmlContent);
    foreach((array) $xmlObject as $index => $node)
        $out[$index] = ( is_object($node) || is_array($node) ) ? XML2Array( $node ) : $node;
    return $out;
}

$page = file_get_contents("http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/index:SCIDIR?query=heart+attack&apiKey=CHAVEAQUI&xml-decode=true&httpAccept=application%2Fxml");
$array = XML2Array($page);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/XML2Array.php).

Se você ainda tiver problemas, provavelmente tem um problema em outro lugar, talvez um XML mal formado.

Comment: sim, peço desculpa mas tinha um coisa mal no meu codigo, estava a chamar mal a função. Agora coloquei tudo ok, mas continua a dar o mesmo erro do implexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: É um pouco estranho dar esse erro porque não tem função com este nome, tem uma função chamada `simplexml_load_string`. A `file_get_contents` retorna uma *string*, portanto está sendo passado o tipo correto para `XML2Srray` e consequentemente para a `simplexml_load_string`. Consegui fazer o teste controlado http://ideone.com/kmOZIi

Comment: @Maniero o problema desse código é que dentro do foreach você aceita que o $node seja um array (na equação ternária onde você verifica se há a necessidade de recursão) entretanto, na entrada do início da função você apenas verifica se é um objeto. Você pode corrigir esse problema de `simplexml_load_string` basicamente substituindo a condiconal para `is_object($xmlContent) || is_array($xmlContent)`

Answer (score -3):

Para quem está com problema com a função descontinuada "each" recriei ela para funcionar no código acima.

```
function legacy_each($array){
    $key = key($array);
    $value = current($array);
    $each = is_null($key) ? false : [
        1        => $value,
        'value'    => $value,
        0        => $key,
        'key'    => $key,
    ];
    next($array);
    return $each;
}
```