# XML imprimindo object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { }

Tags: php, xml

Como transformar um `xml` em um `array` ou objeto?

Faço uma requisição que me retorna o seguinte `xml`:

**xmlteste.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="https://www.twwwireless.com.br/reluzcap/wsreluzcap">
  <xs:schema id="OutDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="OutDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="BuscaSMS">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="seunum" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="celular" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="mensagem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="datarec" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="dataenv" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="datastatus" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="op" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <OutDataSet xmlns="">
      <BuscaSMS diffgr:id="BuscaSMS0" msdata:rowOrder="3">
        <seunum>999999999</seunum>
        <celular>9999999999</celular>
        <mensagem>obrigado</mensagem>
        <status>MO</status>
        <datarec>2018-02-01T13:30:51.547-02:00</datarec>
        <dataenv>2018-02-01T13:30:52.773-02:00</dataenv>
        <datastatus>2018-02-01T13:30:52.773-02:00</datastatus>
        <op>5</op>
      </BuscaSMS>
      <BuscaSMS diffgr:id="BuscaSMS1" msdata:rowOrder="4">
        <seunum>99999999999</seunum>
        <celular>9999999999</celular>
        <mensagem>Obrigado.</mensagem>
        <status>MO</status>
        <datarec>2018-02-01T13:37:17.18-02:00</datarec>
        <dataenv>2018-02-01T13:37:20.807-02:00</dataenv>
        <datastatus>2018-02-01T13:37:20.807-02:00</datastatus>
        <op>5</op>
      </BuscaSMS>
    </OutDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://localhost/xmlteste.xml");
$page = new SimpleXMLElement($page);
var_dump($page);
```

Porém sempre retorna object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { }.
Além disso tentei outros como ([Converter XML para array em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47609/converter-xml-para-array-em-php)), mas infelizmente nada parece funcionar. Alguém pode ajudar?

Estou tentando transforma-lo em array para percorrer os dados contidos na `tag` `<BuscaSMS>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL ; DR**

- [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) não necessariamente irá exibir todos os nós para `SimpleXMLElement`;
- Se não houver erro, significa que o parse ocorreu e o objeto [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) foi criado;
- Pode utilizar [`XPath`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/all/) para buscar um node (nó) em específico;
- A biblioteca [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) é um tanto limitada. As bibliotecas [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) ou [`XML Parser`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) são excelentes alternativas.

**Explicação**

Não é porquê o [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) não está exibindo os nodes que eles não foram carregados. Eles estão lá, e podem ser conferidos se você utilizar o método [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

É importante notar que, apesar de eu utilizar o método [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) nos exemplos mais abaixo, o uso do construtor de [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) segue as mesmas regras de retorno. Que, em caso de erro, retornará ***false***

> Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document, or **FALSE on failure**.

Não há explicação certa sobre o fato de não aparecer no `var_dump` (ao menos eu não localizei), apenas sei que está relacionado com o uso de prefixos do *namespace*.

Caso você remover todos os prefixos, [poderá visualizar o objeto completo, e seus nós, no `var_dump`](https://3v4l.org/sjfdI).

**Navegação entre os nós**

Todavia, a biblioca [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) é um tanto limitada para a manipulação de XMLs complexos, que é o caso que você está tentando. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($simpleXml->children()->asXML());
```

Resultado:

```
bool(false)
```

Não conseguiu localizar nenhum filho para o XML. Agora veja definindo um prefixo de *namespace*:

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($simpleXml->children('diffgr' , true)->asXML());
```

Resultado:

```
string(1017) "<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <OutDataSet xmlns="">
      <BuscaSMS diffgr:id="BuscaSMS0" msdata:rowOrder="3">
        <seunum>999999999</seunum>
        <celular>9999999999</celular>
        <mensagem>obrigado</mensagem>
        <status>MO</status>
        <datarec>2018-02-01T13:30:51.547-02:00</datarec>
        <dataenv>2018-02-01T13:30:52.773-02:00</dataenv>
        <datastatus>2018-02-01T13:30:52.773-02:00</datastatus>
        <op>5</op>
      </BuscaSMS>
      <BuscaSMS diffgr:id="BuscaSMS1" msdata:rowOrder="4">
        <seunum>99999999999</seunum>
        <celular>9999999999</celular>
        <mensagem>Obrigado.</mensagem>
        <status>MO</status>
        <datarec>2018-02-01T13:37:17.18-02:00</datarec>
        <dataenv>2018-02-01T13:37:20.807-02:00</dataenv>
        <datastatus>2018-02-01T13:37:20.807-02:00</datastatus>
        <op>5</op>
      </BuscaSMS>
    </OutDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>"
```

Para que você não tenha que definir manualmente cada namespace procurado, você pode utilizar o método [`SimpleXMLElement::getNamespaces()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php) que lhe trará todos os *namespaces* do XML:

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);    
var_dump($simpleXml->getNamespaces(true));
```

Resultado:

```
array(3) {
  ["xs"]=>
  string(32) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  ["msdata"]=>
  string(36) "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
  ["diffgr"]=>
  string(41) "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
}
```

E assim você poderá ir utilizando o [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) para acessar e navegar por cada nó do XML.

**Pesquisa**

Como você quer apenas acessar os nodes `BuscaSMS`, Você pode utilizar a busca através do [`XPath`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/all/) para tal solução, utilizando o método [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($simpleXml->xpath('//BuscaSMS'));
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (8) {
    ["seunum"]=>
    string(9) "999999999"
    ["celular"]=>
    string(10) "9999999999"
    ["mensagem"]=>
    string(8) "obrigado"
    ["status"]=>
    string(2) "MO"
    ["datarec"]=>
    string(29) "2018-02-01T13:30:51.547-02:00"
    ["dataenv"]=>
    string(29) "2018-02-01T13:30:52.773-02:00"
    ["datastatus"]=>
    string(29) "2018-02-01T13:30:52.773-02:00"
    ["op"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (8) {
    ["seunum"]=>
    string(11) "99999999999"
    ["celular"]=>
    string(10) "9999999999"
    ["mensagem"]=>
    string(9) "Obrigado."
    ["status"]=>
    string(2) "MO"
    ["datarec"]=>
    string(28) "2018-02-01T13:37:17.18-02:00"
    ["dataenv"]=>
    string(29) "2018-02-01T13:37:20.807-02:00"
    ["datastatus"]=>
    string(29) "2018-02-01T13:37:20.807-02:00"
    ["op"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Exemplo prático [neste link](https://3v4l.org/aDdu6).

**Outras bibliotecas**

De qualquer forma, eu recomendo o uso de alguma outra [biblioteca de manipulação de XML](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), tais quais a [`DOM`](https://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) ou [`XML Parser`](https://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php). [Neste link](https://3v4l.org/hhWdo) você pode visualizar o uso da biblioteca [`DOM`](https://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) com o seu XML. Não há necessidade de definições de *namespace*, apenas usá-la.

Já que você gostaria de localizar o node `BuscaSMS`, basta usar o método [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('BuscaSMS') as $buscaSMS)
{
    var_dump($buscaSMS);
}
```

Você pode visualizar o [resultado neste link](https://3v4l.org/1ltTC)

[Neste link](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/563929-duvida-na-hora-de-ler-xml/?tab=comments#comment-2247075), você pode ler uma explicação básica do uso da biblioteca [`DOM`](https://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).