# Ler arquivo xml sem saber nome da tag

Tags: php, xml

Bom dia meus amigo,

Preciso fazer a leitura de um arquivo xml (NF-e) onde possuem vários itens, porém em cada item pode haver uma tag diferente. Nesse caso seriam nas tags de impostos, onde a tag ICMS pode ter vários nomes (ICMS00, ICMS02, ICMS100..), e eu preciso fazer a leitura das tags que possuem dentro.

Exemplo de XML: https://pastebin.com/bXr9pU3C

O código que estou usando e tentando fazer essa leitura é esse:

```
$link = "importacoes/1-42180984431352000191550010001174881191386794.xml"; //link do arquivo xml

$xml = simplexml_load_file($link);

echo $xml->NFe->infNFe->ide->cUF;

foreach($xml->NFe->infNFe->det as $itemm){
    echo '<br>';echo '<br>';
    echo $itemm->prod->cProd;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $itemm->prod->xProd;
    echo '<br>';
    $icms = $itemm->imposto->ICMS;

    print_r($icms);
    echo (string)$icms->ICMS;
}
```

Comment: Existem funções, como DOMDocument::hasChildNodes, que exibe os nodes que possuem filhos, etc... Além disso, todos os nodes são iteráveis. Pode visualizar no seguinte link: https://3v4l.org/hhWdo

Comment: Apesar de não ser a resposta para a pergunta, essa resposta também tem bastante conteúdo (e links) sobre: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274577/5007

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, vou estudar sobre isso, acredito que ali ache o que preciso, obrigado amigo, boa semana!